# where should the adverb 'yet' be put in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am always not sure where to put the adverb 'yet' in a sentence.
In my example below, for me, both versions seem to be correct but if anyone could
double check that would be great.

> I was wondering if you have heard anything back from ... regarding my ... yet?

Or

> I was wondering if you have yet heard anything back from ... regarding my ... ?

Best wishes!

Comment: "if you have heard anything from ... regarding ... yet" or "if you have heard anything from ... yet regarding ...". Your second option may be grammatically correct, but it is not very idiomatic, I think.

Comment: It's probably not idiomatic to include a 'yet' in a sentence this long, and I can't see a case where its omission would lead to loss of clarity. Perhaps most speakers wanting to stick it in would put it after 'back' and pretend there was a large 'breather' comma after it.

Comment: Were the sentence short, it'd be much more idiomatic to place the adverbial _yet_ (in the sense in which you've used it) at the end (_Have you heard anything back from them yet?_). But in a sentence with several adverbials, shorter ones precede longer ones, so _yet_ doesn't come at the end. It comes sooner also in a _to_ construction (_The best/worst is yet to come/be. You've yet to have your finest hour. We are yet to find out whether...)._ Of course, _yet_ can also be a conjunction meaning _but_ (at the beginning of a clause) and a conjuct meaning _however_ (at the beginning of a sentence).

Answer (score 2):

Decisions like these are easier to answer when you shorten the sentence:

> 1. Have you heard back from the doctor **yet**?
> 2. Have you heard back, **yet**, from the doctor?
> 3. Have you **yet** heard back from the doctor?

Options (1) and (3) are more correct and I hear (1) more often. (3) has a slightly archaic quality to it. Option (2) sounds awkward and should be avoided.

Expanding this to your actual question, either of your examples would be acceptable but I recommend the first of the two.

Comment: But if it's a very long sentence, then (3) becomes preferable to (1). *"Have you heard back from the doctor about the results from the tests he did two weeks ago yet?"* sounds quite awkward.

Comment: Yes, good point.